# Botón funciona solo en la primera

Tags: javascript

El `forEach` funciona, trae toda la info de mis `cards` que generé en un array, las funciones de ver más y botón volver funcionan de todas las cards pero me devuelven sólo la información de la primer card.

Éste es el código:

```js
let cards = [
 { url: "https://placehold.it/50/30/eee", city: "A", cajaOculta: "AA1" },
 { url: "https://placehold.it/50/30/ff0", city: "B", cajaOculta: "BB1" },
 { url: "https://placehold.it/50/30/f00", city: "C", cajaOculta: "CC1" }
];
let card = document.getElementById('cards')

cards.forEach((info) => {
  console.log(info)
  card.innerHTML += `
    <div class="card">
        <img src="${info.url}" id="img">
        <a id="city" class="city" onclick="verDescripcion()">${info.city}</a>
        <div id="caja-oculta" style="display: none;">
            <p class="textDesc">"${info.cajaOculta}"</p>
        </div>
        <button id="btnPrev" onclick="botonVolver()"> BACK</button>
    </div>
    `
})

const cajaOculta = document.getElementById('caja-oculta')
const city = document.getElementById('city')
const btnprev = document.getElementById('btnPrev')
const img = document.getElementById('img')


function verDescripcion() {
  if (cajaOculta, card, city, img) {
    cajaOculta.style.display = 'block'
    card.style.background = 'black'
    city.style.display = 'none'
    img.style.display = 'none'
  }
}

function botonVolver() {
  if (cajaOculta, img, card) {
    cajaOculta.style.display = 'none'
    img.style.display = 'block'
    city.style.display = 'block'
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="cards"></div>
```

Comment: Hola Rocio, te damos la bienvenida al sitio. Complete al [tour] para aprender más sobre Stack Overflow y de ese modo ganarás tu primera medalla. He puesto el código como ejecutable para que la gente pueda reproducir el problema.

Comment: Clásico error: [los id deben ser únicos en todo el documento](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id).

Answer (score 4):

El problema es que el código dentro del `forEach` va a generar IDs duplicados. Entonces, al hacer los `document.getElementById` sólo va a seleccionar el primero en vez de el que corresponde al botón que se pulsó (que me imagino es lo que quieres).

Para solucionar esto, lo primero sería cambiar los IDs por clases (los IDs duplicados hacen el HTML no válido). Después, hay varias maneras de solucionarlo. Te pongo un par de ellas: una sería añadir IDs únicos y seleccionar los elementos dentro de las funciones. Otra opción sería seleccionar los elementos en la card del botón que se pulsó.

Aquí te dejo una manera de hacerlo siguiendo ese último método:

```js
let cards = [
 { url: "https://placehold.it/50/30/eee", city: "A", cajaOculta: "AA1" },
 { url: "https://placehold.it/50/30/ff0", city: "B", cajaOculta: "BB1" },
 { url: "https://placehold.it/50/30/f00", city: "C", cajaOculta: "CC1" }
];
let card = document.getElementById('cards')

cards.forEach((info) => {
  console.log(info)
  // he cambiado los IDs con clases para que no haya IDs duplicados
  card.innerHTML += `
    <div class="card">
        <img src="${info.url}" class="img">
        <a class="city" class="city" onclick="verDescripcion()">${info.city}</a>
        <div class="caja-oculta" style="display: none;">
            <p class="textDesc">"${info.cajaOculta}"</p>
        </div>
        <button class="btnPrev" onclick="botonVolver()"> BACK</button>
    </div>
    `
});


function verDescripcion(e) {
  // seleccionamos la card del botón que se pulsó usando la función closest
  const card = event.target.closest(".card");

  // seleccionamos los elementos dentro de esa card con querySelector
  const cajaOculta = card.querySelector('.caja-oculta');
  const city = card.querySelector('.city');
  const btnprev = card.querySelector('.btnPrev');
  const img = card.querySelector('.img');

  if (cajaOculta, card, city, img) {
    cajaOculta.style.display = 'block'
    card.style.background = 'black'
    city.style.display = 'none'
    img.style.display = 'none'
  }
}

function botonVolver() {
  // seleccionamos la card del botón que se pulsó usando la función closest
  const card = event.target.closest(".card");

  // seleccionamos los elementos dentro de esa card con querySelector
  const cajaOculta = card.querySelector('.caja-oculta');
  const city = card.querySelector('.city');
  const img = card.querySelector('.img');

  if (cajaOculta, img, card) {
    cajaOculta.style.display = 'none'
    img.style.display = 'block'
    city.style.display = 'block'
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="cards"></div>
```

---

Como referencia:

- [`.closest()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Element/closest): selecciona el primer ancestro que cumpla con el selector especificado como parámetro. Con este método seleccionamos la card que contiene el botón pulsado.
- [`.querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelector): devuelve el primer descendiente que cumpla con el selector pasado como parámetro. Está función normalmente se usa con `document` pero puede usarse con cualquier elemento.

Comment: Genial! entendí el problema y funciono. Muchas gracias

Comment: @RocioMaldonado Recuerda marcar la respuesta como aceptada si así te parece. Saludos https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/427/c%c3%b3mo-funciona-la-aceptaci%c3%b3n-de-respuestas/428#428

Answer (score 2):

Tal como te dicen en la otra respuesta, uno de los problemas es que estás generando valores `id` duplicados, por lo cual al buscar en el DOM un elemento por su `id` usando `document.getElementById` te traerá el primero que encuentra.

Por mi parte pienso que podrías usar el mismo método, tanto para el elemento tipo `anchor` como para el botón. He ajustado un poco el código para reutilizar la función. Además he utilizado la propiedad CSS [`visibility`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/visibility) y el método [`toggle`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Element/classList#toggle) del objeto `classList` del elemento.

He creado una clase de CSS:

- `.oculta`, que aplica la visibildad del elemento como `hidden` (oculta) y una altyura máxima de `0`, para que el elemento no ocupe espacio en la página.

```css
.oculta {
  visibility: hidden;
  max-height: 0;
}
```

De esta forma, cada vez que se ejecuta la función, se buscan los elementos, usando el valor correcto de `id` y se hace un cambio de la clase aplicada.

Para poder crear de forma dinámica el `id` del elemento, usamos el valor del índice de `cards` que estamos recorriendo, para ello hacemos, por ejemplo: `id="caja-oculta-${index}"`, lo cual nos devolverá algo como `id="caja-oculta-0"` para el caso de `index` igual a `0`.

Por último, he almacenado el valor de `index` como propiedad del elemento usando un atributo [`data-*`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes), que me permitirá construir el valor del `id` del elemento apropiado cuando se hace clic en el elemento que tiene asociada la acción.

El código funcional se puede ver a continuación:

```js
let cards = [
 { url: "https://placehold.it/50/30/eee", city: "A", cajaOculta: "AA1" },
 { url: "https://placehold.it/50/30/ff0", city: "B", cajaOculta: "BB1" },
 { url: "https://placehold.it/50/30/f00", city: "C", cajaOculta: "CC1" }
];
let card = document.getElementById('cards')

cards.forEach((info, index) => {
  card.innerHTML += `
    <div class="card">
        <img src="${info.url}" id="img-${index}">
        <a
          id="city-${index}"
          data-index="${index}"
          onclick="toggleDescription(this)">
            ${info.city}
        </a>
        <div id="caja-oculta-${index}" class="oculta">
            <p class="textDesc">"${info.cajaOculta}"</p>
        </div>
        <button id="btnPrev-${index}" data-index="${index}" onclick="toggleDescription(this)"> BACK</button>
    </div>
    `
})

function toggleDescription(element) {
  const city = document.getElementById(`city-${element.dataset.index}`);
  const caja = document.getElementById(`caja-oculta-${element.dataset.index}`);
  const img = document.getElementById(`img-${element.dataset.index}`);
  if (caja, city, img) {
    city.classList.toggle('oculta');
    caja.classList.toggle('oculta');
    img.classList.toggle('oculta');
  }
}
```

```css
.oculta {
  visibility: hidden;
  max-height: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="cards"></div>
```